# How to download a .do file in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to download this webpage with python http://webapps.rrc.state.tx.us/CMPL/viewPdfReportFormAction.do?method=cmplW2FormPdf&packetSummaryId=18029

It downloads normally if I right click and click save as it is automatically recognized as a pdf. However, the page is being displayed by a web application and has a .do file extension. When i download with python urllib, urllib2, or request then try to open it is always corrupted...

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: Nothing is working. Not even wget http://webapps.rrc.state.tx.us/CMPL/viewPdfReportFormAction.do?method=cmplW2FormPdf&packetSummaryId=18029

Comment: Interesting, my wget is hanging too.